# CSS width 100% doesn't work properly on 22'' monitor

Tags: html, css

Here is [HTML](http://artimax.su/new/index1.html) and [CSS](http://artimax.su/new/default2.css).

On 17'' and 19'' screen it looks nice. How I could catch the bug?
Please help.

Comment: A 22-foot monitor? Sign me up!

Comment: I've found that using the Firefox extension FireBug helps a lot. It can show you margin/padding/position of all your divs.

Comment: I can't debug it. I have only 19' monitor and on all browsers it works ok. But customer have 22' and he want it to be full screen( And left side of fixed size).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't want the content area to be as wide as the whole maximized browser window?

you need to give your #wrapper div a set width, then all the other divs can assume a width of 100% from it.

For example,

```
#wrapper
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:960px;
}
```

Comment: +1 as looking at the example this seems to be what the question is about.

Comment: I (customer) want it to be max width. left part fixed, right part the rest of screen

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`<html>
    <body style="margin:0px;">
        <div style="padding-left:50px;text-align:left;">
            <div style="border:solid 1px red;width:100%;">content here</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`